# Oculus Rift add 3D object to url

Tags: 3d, virtual-reality, oculus

I want to add a 3D object to my oculus game but I want to source it online. This way if I want to change the object it won't require updating the whole game just off of my web server.

Is there a way to add it and or require a download each time the game is loaded. What about only once the person will see it or come close to seeing it (to keep the server load down)

Comment: This is entirely possible but it really has nothing to do specifically with VR and everything to do with what engine technology you are using.

Comment: I haven't really started with oculus at all. I have been looking at online frameworks with WebVR. trying to see what oculus offers. Any engines you suggest? I will check unity because that seems to be a mainstay

Comment: Unity is a good choice for VR development and probably the most widely used engine right now for VR. It also has a vibrant ecosystem through the asset store where you are quite likely to be able to find add-ons / plug-ins that will help you with downloading an object dynamically.

Comment: Okay. I'll take a look at the plugin section then.